# Swap function arguments

Tags: macro, refactor

When refactoring code it would be useful to be able to swap function arguments.

Changing for eg:

```
func(foo[0], bar(), baz.spam)
```

into

```
func(baz.spam, foo[0], bar())
```

Is there some way to swap arguments to the left/right, keeping function parentheses and commas in place?

---

Note, this *could* become quite involved if you want to account for arguments which themselves are function calls with their own arguments - eg: `func(baz->spam, foo[0], bar(a, b, c))` - supporting these cases would likely involve some more comprehensive parsing.

Answer (score 32):

#### Without plugins

> | indicates cursor position

```
func(foo[0], bar(), |baz.spam)
```

Steps:

1. `dt)` will delete `baz.spam`
2. `Ff` will move the cursor to the character f in `foo[0]`
3. `vt,p` will delete foo[0] and replace it with `baz.spam`
4. `$P` will paste the foo[0] before the parens
5. Repeat steps 1-4 for any others.

#### With plugins

- [vim-argumentative](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) by *Peter Rincker* : Provides text objects for moving around function arguments (Default mappings: `<,` and `>,`).
- [vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange.git) by *Tom McDonald* : Provides handy mappings to exchange two selections (Default mappings: `cx` in normal mode and `X` in visual mode).
- [vim-sideways](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) by *Andrew Radev* : Move function arguments (and other delimited-by-something items) left and right (Default mappings: `NA`).
- [vim-swap](https://github.com/machakann/vim-swap) by *machakann* : Reorder delimited items (Default mappings: `g<` and `g>`).

Comment: the non-plugin solution is very specific for the case...

Comment: @elyashiv the idea is that you can use a similar technique for any function arguments. Basically, yank a word, visually select another word, paste, which Vim will yank the deleted character to the register, and then paste where you first yanked from.

Comment: +1 for vim-sideways! The last section describes a very nice feature: `cia`  to "change in argument". ❤️

Answer (score 6):

I present 3 methods. The first two are particular cases, which require less keystrokes. The last one is generic.
`|` represents the cursor position.

---

### Swap adjacent arguments (doesn't work for last two)

```
function func(foo[0], |bar(), baz.spam, qux->norf)
```

Steps:

1. `dW` delete the current Word (argument)
2. `W` go to the first char of the next argument
3. `P` paste before the cursor

### Swap last two arguments

```
function func(foo[0], bar()|, baz.spam, qux->norf)
```

Steps:

1. `dt,` delete until next comma
2. `E` go to last character of the next argument
3. `P` paste before the cursor

### Swap any two arguments

```
function func(|foo[0], bar(), baz.spam, qux->norf)
```

Steps:

1. `vt,d` visually delete until comma
2. `W` several times until you reach the argument you want to swap with
3. `gP` paste before cursor and place cursor on the char after pasted content
4. `dt,` delete until next comma. replace `,` by `)` if this is the last argument
5. `` `< `` go back to the beggining of the last visual area (cursor will be placed at the comma)
6. `P` paste before the cursor

---

Edit: as pointed by @aharris88 the OP wants the last argument to be the first and move all the others right.

### Rotate arguments to the right

```
function func(foo[0], bar(), baz.spam|, qux->norf)
```

Steps:

1. `dw` delete `,␣`
2. `dt)` delete last argument
3. `%p` jump to opening parentheses and paste last argument
4. `a,␣` insert a comma and space
5. `<Esc>` return to normal mode

Or, if you don't want to ever leave normal mode:

1. `"rdw` delete `,␣` into a register `r`
2. `dt)` delete last argument
3. `%p` jump to opening parentheses and paste last argument
4. `"rp` paste content of register `r`

---

Bonus: a GIF for each case:
[swap1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Y0e.gif), [swap2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y34mT.gif), [swap3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHPzV.gif) and [rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJSKt.gif)

Comment: While this answer does swap arguments, it doesn't answer the question, which is how to move the last argument to the beginning.

Comment: @aharris88, you are right. I edited my answer.