# Programming-oriented word swap using transwrd.vim

Tags: regular-expression

The plugin transwrd.vim allows to to easily swap two words by pressing `<A-t>` while having cursor on the latter word.
For example:  `two words` becomes `words two`.

I think the pattern which designates a word is contained in the `g:transwrd_wordpattern` variable and is (as default) the following: `\k\+`

Is it possible to define an advanced pattern which allows to be more programming language savvy (while still working for normal words)? Eg.

```
param[0], param[1]  -->  param[1], param[0]
int call1()         -->  call1() int
```

This way it could also be used to swap function arguments (related to this other [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/609/swap-function-arguments)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you can come up with a regular expression that will, alone, capture everything you consider to be a "word." The plugin uses the pattern stored in `g:transwrd_wordpattern` to identify words by finding two matches and then swapping the characters in the matched ranges.

Doing `let g:transwrd_wordpattern='[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\(\)]\+'` will, for example, let it match both of your examples.

Comment: Good! Thinking about it, I included in the list between `[` and `]` after the 9, the char `_` in order to consider as "word" identifiers like foo_bar